# Filtering on an indexed value in a CommaSeparatedIntegerField

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a model class which has a comma separated integer field which maps to a Postgres integer array field.

```
class Observation(models.Model):
    frequencies = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=200)
```

What I want to be able to do is use the filter (or something else suitable) interface to do a comparison on an indexed value in the array. 
Example:

```
Observation.objects.filter(frequencies[100]__equals = 10)
```

I know I can not do this and I can not see in the documentation how to index an array field in the filter interface. I want this action to be performed by the SQL in the database (may have to do it in code?).

I know I can use the extra() feature but I want to know if there is a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt there is a way to search that array on the DB layer, since that field type is saved as a charfield (in MySQL at least). Using extra() with SUBSTRING() seems to me the best way fordward: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself needing to search particular entities within a comma-separated field, you should probably consider whether that's the correct format for your data. Perhaps a foreign key to a separate table might be more appropriate.